# jQuery + PHP exec

Tags: php, jquery

Есть простой пример в котором вызывается exec

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td><?echo "Сервер";?></td>
    <td><?$result = exec ('uptime'); echo $result;?></td>
</tr>
```

Как обернуть второе поле в ссылку чтоб возвращала значение exec не перезагружая всю страницу ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно делать ajax запрос на сервер и ответ писать в выбранную ячейку.
Простой пример:

файл index.php

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Сервер</td>
        <td><button id="btn-uptime">get uptime</button></td>
        <td id="result"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    const tdResult = document.querySelector('#result');
    document.querySelector('#btn-uptime').addEventListener('click', () => {
        fetch('/uptime.php')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(time => tdResult.innerHTML = time);
    });
</script>
```

файл uptime.php

```
<?php

echo exec('uptime');
```

Answer (score 0):

Не удается включить в цикле
**index.php**

```
<?php
$file_name = "data.txt";
$data = file( $file_name );
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Сервер</td>
        <td>push button</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    foreach( $data as $value ):
    $value = explode( "|", $value );
?>
    <tr>
        <td>Сервер</td>
        <td><button id="btn-uptime">echo row</button></td>
        <td id="<?=trim($value[0])?>"><?=trim($value[0])?></td>
    </tr>

<script>
    const tdResult = document.querySelector('#<?=trim($value[0])?>');
    document.querySelector('#btn-uptime').addEventListener('click', () => {
        fetch('echo_row.php')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(time => tdResult.innerHTML = time);
    });
</script>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
</table>
```

**echo_row.php**

```
<?php
echo exec('echo R_'.$_POST["row_name"]);
```

**data.txt**

```
row1
row2
row3
```

Предполагается что нажатие на каждую кнопку будет возвращать результат скрипта который отработал с соответствующем значением для каждого поля из цикла.
Прошу помочь в решении.

Comment: - не работает для каждой из кнопок,- нет представления как передать POST